# how to create multiple dojo buttons after looping through an array

Tags: button, dynamic, dojo

After looping through my array, I am building multiple buttons based on the array objects. However, I want to dynamically build the buttons using dojo buttons or dijit buttons from the array. How can I do that?

This is what I have:

```
array.forEach(this.DYNAMIC_FILTER_FORMS, function (entry, i) {
//console.debug(entry, "at index", i);

var button = domConstruct.create("button", {
    id: "menuBtn" + i,
    class: "menuBtnClass",
    "name": entry.menuText,
    "value": entry.menuText
}, dom.byId("content"));
button.innerHTML = entry.menuText;
```

I want something like this, but multiple buttons from an array:

```
// Create a button programmatically:
var myButton = new Button({
    label: "Click me!",
    onClick: function(){
        // Do something:
        dom.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
    }
}, "progButtonNode").startup();
```

Comment: Your first piece of code does already work for me? :o http://jsfiddle.net/ujzomw8q/

Answer (score 0):

```
array.forEach(this.DYNAMIC_FILTER_FORMS, function (entry, i) {
    var myButton = new Button({
        label: entry.menuText,
        onClick: function(){ ... }
    });
    myButton.placeAt("content");
});
```